# How to create barchart using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have a data set that show all the countries confirmed covid cases per day for 7 months.

[image: Data Frame Head]

How do I create a bar chart that shows just the countries name and its overall cases in the 7 month period. I am trying to groupby "Country/Region" but I dont know how to combine each countries different days into one total so I can plot the two.

```
covid_stats_country =covid_stats.groupby("Country/Region").sum()
```

[image]

```
covid_stats.plt.plot(x="Country/Region",y="Confirmed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your grouped dataframe for the plot:

```
>>> covid_stats_country["Confirmed"].plot.bar()
```

[image: bar chart]